# logback.xml - pattern layout- How to confirgure response's content length

Tags: playframework, logback

Here's the access log configuration that I have in my logback.xml for playframework.

```
<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.dir.access}/access.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg %n %b</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>

    </encoder>
</appender>
```

I am using %b in pattern tag to get response content length but I get this error:

ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@3a7e4535 - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [b]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@3a7e4535 - [b] is not a valid conversion word.

I believe there's a conversion class that is missing for [b]. Can somebody please let me know what is the conversion class and how to configure it in logback.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using "logback-classic". The %b seems only to be available in [logback-access](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-access) judging from the docs at: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

> PatternLayout in logback-access can be configured in much the same way
>   as its classic counterpart. However it features additional conversion
>   specifiers suited for logging particular bits of information available
>   only in HTTP servlet requests and HTTP servlet responses.